# Centos 5 virtual machine (32 bit) installation on Xen

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

I dnt know how to install centos in xen virtual machine. Any one have some installation step send it to me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places where you can get readymade images for e.g. [here](http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusUserImageCreatorGuide_v1.6). Once you install one you can make changes to it and export your own custom image